# Android - LazyList, how to get the source name of each image?

Tags: android, image, asynchronous, onitemclick, lazylist

I'm using the LazyList project of thest1 [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and I want the name of the image when I click on it.

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id + "", 2000).show();

        }
    });
```

I can only get the id of each image. But I need the full name (source) of each image to show it on the browser and download it. How can I do this?

Comment: you have the adapter view and the position, what else do you need ? (isn't parent.getItemAtPosition(position) sufficient ?)

Comment: with parent.getItemAtPosition(position) I just get the number (I think it's the id number) of each image.

Comment: no, you get a String from the array you passed to the LazyAdapter

Comment: and what can I do with this String number? I want to do something like this: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg"))); therefore I need the source name.

Comment: what do you mean, String number ? the String is the url

Comment: you could also use `whateverYouStringArrayIsNamed[position]`, if you are more comfortable with this approach

Comment: yessss it works with whateverYouStringArrayIsNamed[position]! and it was so easy, silly me :D thank you